# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, x86-64, armv7

I try to build my project and get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlurryAnalytics", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Did you updated your Flurry library? If not look for any latest version they have.

Comment: @gagarwal I use cocoa pods. I am not sure if the latest one flurry library has new architecture. I am using pod 'FlurrySDK', '~> 5.4'

Comment: Make sure your Cocoapod targets are having arm64 in "ARCHS" and "VALID_ARCHS", i.e. your pods are compiled for arm64 architecture.

Comment: as this link says http://support.flurry.com/?title=Analytics/GettingStarted that 5.4 version supports Xcode 6

Comment: @gagarwal in my cocoa pods setting I have $(ARCHS_STANDARD)

Comment: I believe you are using Xcode 6+. If yes $(ARCHS_STANDARD) should include arm64 by default. What about "VALID_ARCHS" settings I asked for, look under your flurry pod target. If possible post a screenshot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63514/discussion-between-gagarwal-and-matrosov-alexander).